grep regex for lines with digit pairs (or more)
I've been working out how to formulate the proper regex, where the file format is such:
2999 1245 8765 2323
4545 1213 1332 6543
1234 4567 6789 0124
1234 5678 9012 3456

Matching only lines that have consecutive matching integers.  Spaces between do not matter.
The above should return:
2999 1245 8765 2323
# [9][9][9] meets the requirement 
4545 1213 1332 6543
# [3][3] meets the requirement 
1234 4567 6789 0124
# [4][4] over the space separated still holds

The last line does not match.
So far I have been trying:
$ grep -E '([0-9]+) \1' input-file.txt

Where the \1 is the group but I don't match all of the possible groups.

You need to make the space optional.  And you probably don't want to make the digit match repeated; what you have now will match multi-digit patterns such as 123 123.

Re terminology: you are matching digits, not integers. This threw me for a loop for a minute when reading your question body.

I suggest you change the title to (sic), "grep regex to match lines containing a pair of the same digit separated by zero or one spaces".

You can also try (\d)(?: ?\1)+

@bobblebubble I had been missing the literal space in the regex pattern.  Here I was doing the exercise with a partial pattern in place already.  The \s (as I normally would have) vs. a literal space itself was the part I was unaccustomed to.  Thanks again!

I suggest:
grep -E '([0-9]) ?\1+' file

Output:
2999 1245 8765 2323
4545 1213 1332 6543
1234 4567 6789 0124

Quantifiers check to see how many times to search for a character:
?: zero or one
+: one or more
*: zero or more

But why would the ? "zero or more" match the missing lines?  Is it because it matches the "previous" token?

Quantifiers always refer to the character directly to the left of it.

No need for the +, matching 1 repetition is enough.

@tijko regarding 'But why would the ? "zero or more" match the missing lines?' - it doesn't, what makes you think it does?

@EdMorton I wasn't thinking about the pattern in terms of the space being a literal identifier.  I've always used \s.  The literal space was throwing me off.  Thank you for your help!

\s isn't portable. It only means space in PCREs and GNU implementations of some Unix tools. For portability to all tools that use POSIX BREs or EREs (or PCREs) use the POSIX character class [[:space:]] instead of \s and [^[:space:]] instead of \S. Similarly for \w ([[:alnum:]_]) and \d ([[:digit:]]).
